# Conditional result based on previous result

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a formula that results in either Buy, Sell or Hold. The formula looks like this: `=IF(D3>0.01,"Buy",IF(D3<-0.01,"Sell","Hold"))`

As you can see it is based on what the value is in column D, the issue comes from the fact that a Buy or Sell result can be issued several times in a row but as you can imagine you can't buy something you have already bought and you can't sell something you have already sold.

So what i would like the formula to do is if the outcome is SELL then any subsequent SELL outcomes become HOLD until a BUY result occurs, and the same with BUY, any additional BUY results are changed to HOLD until a SELL result occurs. i.e only one Sell or one Buy in a row, interspersed with as many Hold results as required.

Hope this is clear, its hard enough to explain with words. Not sure if it helps but here is a screen grab. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screen Shot - ignore the top line of n/a]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array formula to find the `MAX` `ROW` before the current row where column C is "Buy" or "Sell", then compare those.

```
SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))
//versus
SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell")))
```

(The `SUMPRODUCT` just makes sure that this section of code is evaluated as an array formula.  The `C$1` means that it locks to the top as you drag it down)

Include this as part of your `IF`, since you only want to Buy/Sell if the most recent action was the opposite.  (i.e. Buy only if `BuyRow` ≤ `SellRow`, and vice-versa)

This means that your "Time to Buy" check becomes `AND(D3>0.01, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))<=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell"))))`, so the full formula becomes:

```
IF(AND(D3>0.01, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))<=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell")))), "Buy", IF(AND(D3<-0.01, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))>=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell")))), "Sell", "Hold"))
```

(The `>=` and `<=` are important, because for the first action both `BuyRow` and `SellRow` will be `0`.  This *does* mean that by changing one of them to exclude the `=` you can tell it which action to do first!)

Comment: Hi Chronocidal, i really appreciate you explaining what each part is doing, i am trying to learn how it all works rather than just get answers but i'll be honest this is really beyond me. The good news is it works perfectly so thank you very much.

Comment: Actually Chronocidal, it suddenly stops working from row 18, i have no idea why. Would it be possible for you to have a look? Microsoft One Drive link: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ao0OmnEKfEp00XpgTfuo9rx05xR3

Comment: Looking at your data, the issue is that after you Sell at Row 17, then *selling* will make the %change positive (but you can't sell stuff you don't have) but *buying* or *holding* will leave it negative (which is "sell or hold" territory).  This is caused by the fact that the "Live Price" never goes over the "Price at last action" after that point

Comment: Yes you are right, that is because i didn't know what the formula was to make that work properly in all situations. So when it is in a 'Buying phase' I want Column B to always keep the very highest price the stock went up to during that whole time but during a 'Selling phase' I want column B to show the very lowest price the stock went down to. Would you possible be able to help me on that formula too, really appreciate your time. Thanks Chronocidal.

Comment: Well, you have code in the answer to decide if the last thing you did was "Buy" or "Sell".  If by "that whole time" you mean since Row 1, you can just use `MAX` and `MIN`, and only lock the first row (e.g. `MAX(A$1:A2)` but if you mean since the last "Sell"/"Buy" then you'll need an array formula to `MIN`/`MAX` where `ROW` is ≥ the previous action

Comment: It is the latter, so the MAX / MIN since the last "Buy"/"Sell". So the highest price since last "Buy" and then switching to the lowest price since last "Sell".

I've played around with the formula you gave me and got this but can't get it quite right:

=IF(AND(B3>0.01, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))<=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell")))), A3, IF(AND(B3<-0.01, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))>=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell")))), A2, B1))

Comment: To see what you did last, just check which of the first 2 `SUMPRODUCTS` is larger, like so:  `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy")))>SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell"))), "Last action was Buy","Last action was Sell")`.  As for the number values, here are Largest number since last "Buy": `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(A$1:A2*--(ROW(A$1:A2)>=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Buy"))))))` and Smallest number since last "Sell": `=SUMPRODUCT(MIN(A$1:A2+1E+99*--(ROW(A$1:A2)>=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(C$1:C2)*--(C$1:C2="Sell"))))))`

Comment: I added those 3 lines of code together into one cell but it just says #VALUE! - What did I do wrong?

Comment: That link above is still active if you wanted to have a look.

Comment: did you have a chance to look at your formula above to see if it's correct or why it might not be working? Thanks.

Comment: Running through with the "Evaluate Formula" tool under "Formulas", it becomes fairly obvious that the issue is in row 1.  The value in Column A is a string, not a number, so returns a `#VALUE!` error.  Since `N(..)` does not work with arrays (and for some reason `AGGREGATE` function excludes the `#VALUE!` in a Range but not in an Array?) you can just change all the `$1` in the formula to `$2` and exclude the header row

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
=IF(and(D3>0.01, c2<>"Buy"),"Buy", IF(and(D3<-0.01, c2<>"Sell"), "Sell", "Hold"))
```

Comment: Your formula very nearly worked Jeeped but if the previous hold was the wrong sign then it would generate a new buy or sell even if it was already a buy or sell preciously. i.e:

Buy +5%,  
Hold -0.8%,  
Buy +4%  

In that above example the sell was never triggered so i would like it to not generate another buy after the hold.